# Swift CloudKit QueryOperation Duplicates

Tags: swift, swift2, cloudkit

When I perform a query operation, despite only having 501 records in the cloudkit dashboard, I get around 1542 results (all duplicates).

This is my code:

```
    func queryForTable() -> Void {

    self.arrayOfFoodItems.removeAllObjects()

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()        
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "FoodItems", predicate: resultPredicate)

    let queryOp = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    executeQueryOperation(queryOp, onOperationQueue: operationQueue)

}

func executeQueryOperation(queryOperation: CKQueryOperation, onOperationQueue operationQueue: NSOperationQueue){

    queryOperation.database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = self.addRecordToArray
    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if cursor != nil {
        if let queryCursor = cursor{
            let queryCursorOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: queryCursor)
            self.executeQueryOperation(queryCursorOperation, onOperationQueue: operationQueue)
        }
        }
        else {
            self.sortToSectionsAndReloadData()
        }
    }

    operationQueue.addOperation(queryOperation)

}
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: Here's the other 2 functions I'm using. As stated in the comments, I'm calling queryForTable() in viewDidLoad.

```
func sortToSectionsAndReloadData() {

    for (var i = 0; i < self.arrayOfSections.count; i++) {

        self.arrayOfArrays[i].removeAllObjects()

        let prefix:String = self.arrayOfSections[i]
        let array:NSMutableArray = self.arrayOfArrays[i] as! NSMutableArray

        for object in self.arrayOfFoodItems {

            let name = object["itemName"] as! String

            if name.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(prefix.lowercaseString) {

                array.addObject(object)
            }

        }
    }

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func addRecordToArray (record: CKRecord!) {

    self.arrayOfFoodItems.addObject(record)

    let recordItemName = record["itemName"]

    print("\(recordItemName)")

}
```

Comment: Show the other 2 functions you're using

Answer (score 0):

With each queryCompletionBlock you will receive all record that are fetched up to the cursor. So the first query you will get a result of about 100 records, then 200, then 300, then 400 and then 500. In your case you add those to your results each time. If you add these up, then you end up with 1500 records. So instead of adding the results to your data array you should replace the data array with the results.

Comment: That is probably not the problem.  Records are added by the recordFetchedBlock as they are received.   Since the cursor provided to the queryCompletionBlock is used for the next query operation, it is expected to  "continue" from where it left off (that is the purpose of a cursor) and not restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture that the queryForTable() function is getting called again before the previous call has completed its query operation.   You would get parallel queries feeding your array, which gets reinitialized by the last queryForTable() but still receives data from the ongoing queries that have not yet finished receiving data.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! Thanks! But how would I ensure that queryForTable is only called after the previous call has completed its queryOperation? I'm calling queryForTable in viewDidLoad now. I saw something that might help, but it's in Objective-C and I'm not sure how to implement it. Thanks a lot!      `@synchronized (self) 
    {
        // Quickly returns if another loadNextBatch is running or we have the oldest post
        if(self.isLoadingBatch || self.haveOldestPost) return;
        else self.isLoadingBatch = YES;
    }`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711139/cloudkit-preventing-duplicate-records)

Comment: Oh, and I had another [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691032/querying-private-database-in-swift-for-user-details). I'm not sure if it's the same problem because I'm using a simple query and not  a queryOperation for that, so I think should only be querying once. Thanks again!

Comment: You should first make sure that this is indeed the issue.  Perhaps by printing something at start and end of query processing.   If it is, you could use an internal "inProgress" flag to exit from queryForTable() if a previous query cycle is still going.